# Accessing Liferay contents remotely Giving exception Permission Checker not initialized

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, liferay

I am accessing the content from  rest service   using DLAppServiceUtil but it is giving me PermissionChecker not initialized

```
long repositoryId = Long.parseLong(temp);
         String Foldername="";
         long groupId=Long.parseLong(temp);
         long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;
        java.util.List<Folder> lFolder;
        try {
                lFolder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolders(repositoryId, parentFolderId);
                for (Folder folder : lFolder)
                {

                      Foldername=folder.getName();
                      if(Foldername.equals(project_name))
                      {
                          folder_ID = folder.getFolderId();
                          break;    
                      }   
                }


        }
```

Comment: You have to specify liferay user credential(with required role permission) in rest service url.

Comment: Any help about specifying user credentials????

Comment: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/service-security-layers-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-05-en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to link below.

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/service-security-layers-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-05-en

Regards